# How to check for back slash in input?

Tags: java, comparison

I have to check for character sequences like \chapter{Introduction} from the strings read from a file. To do this I have to first check for the occurence of backslash.

This is what I did

```
 final char[] chars = strLine.toCharArray();
         char c;
         for(int i = 0; i<chars.length; i++ ){
            c = chars[i];
            if(c ==  '\' ) {

            }
         }
```

But the backslash is treated as an escape sequence rather than a character.

Any help on how to this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean backslash? `\ ` is a backslash, `/` is a forward slash (which is a perfectly normal character)

Comment: You have to write the \ character twice, i.e. c == "\\".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The backward slash is an escape character. If you want to represent a real backslach, you have to use two backslashes (it's then escaping itself). Further, you also need to denote characters by singlequotes, not by doublequotes. So, this should work:

```
if (c == '\\')
```

#### See also:

- [JLS 3.10.4 - Character Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100960)
- [JLS 3.10.6 - Escape Sequences](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#101089)

Answer (score 4):

You might also consider using the `contains()` and/or `indexOf()` methods for `String`.  They will save you the trouble of iterating over each character in any given line.

Here's an example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("java Test string1 string2 ...");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        for (String inputStr : args) {
            if(inputStr.contains("\\")) {
                System.out.println("Found at: " + inputStr.indexOf("\\"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

A backslash character can be represented in Java source code as `'\\'`.

```
final char[] chars = strLine.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == '\\') {
        // is a backslash
    }
}
```